# iPad app for filesharing that doesn't stop uploads after iPad gets auto-locked

Tags: ipad-app, uploader, file-sharing

I'm trying to upload a large file from my iPad (iPadOS 13) to make it accessible to my computer, which runs Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.  I [cannot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/415979/20338) disable auto-lock on my iPad (iPadOS 13) (the maximum auto-lock period is 15 minutes), and whenever the iPad gets locked, uploads are stopped when using Google Drive and SendAnywhere. My file will take approximately one hour for the upload to finish given my current network speed.

I'm therefore looking for an iPad that doesn't stop uploads after getting auto-locked. Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Filemail](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filemail-send-large-files/id665033466) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324065237if_/https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filemail-send-large-files/id665033466)) (gratis) doesn't stop uploads after getting auto-locked. No registration required to send up to 50 GB. No ads + fast servers in my very limited experience.

[image]